# How to select specific column from the sheet and display in the excel vba list box

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Dim lastRow As Long
idRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
questionRow = sh.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ID", RefersToLocal:=sh.Range("A2:B" & idRow)
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Question", RefersToLocal:=sh.Range("G2:L" & questionRow)
With Me.listBox2
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnCount = 8
    .ColumnWidths = "30,85,85,85,85,85,85,85"
    .RowSource = "ID"
    .RowSource = "Question"
    End With
End Sub
```

This code only populate the list box with the data of question. How to populate the list box with both "ID" and "Question" when the form is activated? Please help!

Comment: I assigned the width of the unwanted column to 0 and it works well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `.RowSource =` will overwrite the first. So either you fill the listbox manually with VBA (not using `.RowSource`, you will find tutorials on that) or you take all the columns between `ID` and `Question`, but you cannot have both columns if they are not continous.

Try `.RowSource = "ID:Question"` this will take all columns from `ID` to `Question`. Note you can hide columns by changing their `.ColumnWidths` to `0`. For example `.ColumnWidths = "30,0,40,50"` will show 3 rows because the second row width is `0` and hidden.